# Is there a way to resize a picture for fitting a block of a pop-up window in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, image-size, wordpress-shortcode

I would like to require your help because I'm building a new website in WordPress and I bought an existing theme (Ciya Shop), but when I try to modify the pop-up (in woo commerce option) I have to do it through coding. To be more specific about the issue, I want to change the picture that appears as default but when I try to do it, the new image never corresponds to the right dimensions of the frame and when I change the sizes, its quality is affected. I will leave the original code here:

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
<div class="promo-image col-sm-6">
<div class="vc_column-inner ">
<figure><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-39396" src="https:...." alt="" width="2240" height="1260" /></figure>
</div>
</div>
<div class="promo-content col">
<div class="promo-popup-info">
<h5>Hello User</h5>
<h4 class="heading">Join Our Newsletter</h4>
Subscribe to the CiyaShop mailing list to receive updates on new arrivals, special offers and other discount information.

[pgscore_newsletter mailchimp_id="demo_test" mailchimp_api_key="demo_test"]

</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Providing information is not enough to answer the question. Either provide the HTML & CSS from your website or provide the page url and explain which section/image you have the issue with so that it could be reviewed. also, leave the original and modified both designs on the page so that they could be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the resizing by CSS.
Your picture's class is `.promo-image` as we can see in the html code you shared.
What you need to do is to use `height` and `width` rulers.

example;

```
.promo-image{
height:500px;
width:100%;
}
```

or

```
.promo-image{
height:20%;
width:100px;
}
```

or

```
.promo-image{
height:70px;
width:200px;
}
```

also when you resize a picture with this method you should also change the size of the picture in the mobile version since this wont be a responsive image sizing.
and you can achieve this simply adding this the beginning of the same code.

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 479px){
.promo-image{
 height:70px;
 width:200px;
}
}
```

If you have any questions please ask.